# Alter style bits of initialized controls

Tags: java, swt

Is it possible to alter the [style bits](https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWT_Widget_Style_Bits) of SWT controls after initialization? I know I can pass them to the constructor, but I wonder if I can also change them after having called the constructor. I know that I can do so for the layout-related information, but how about bits such as `SWT.READ_ONLY` on a combo box for example?

Is there anything such as (imaginary code):

```
Combo cmbExample = new Combo(s, SWT.NONE);
// ...
cmbExample.setStyleBit(SWT.READ_ONLY);
```

Answer (score 3):

No, the style bits are fixed and cannot be changed.

One reason for this is that the SWT implementation for a platform may actually create completely different native controls depending on the style.

For example on macOS the read only `Combo` uses `NSPopUpButton` whereas the read write `Combo` uses `NSComboBox`.

There is the occasional exception - `StyledText` has `setEditable` which overrides the `SWT.READ_ONLY` style, but most controls don't do this.